# What are usage and filter fields for in actions of type ir.actions.act_window in Odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-13

When you create an action to open a view in Odoo (`ir.actions.act_window`) there is a set of fields you can use to customize the way in which the views are shown.

There is a couple of fields, `usage` and `filter`, that I don't understand very well. The field `usage` has the following comment:

> Used to filter menu and home actions from the user form.

But actually I've only find one action using it in the whole code, an action which gives it the value `menu`:

```
<field name="usage">menu</field>
```

There are more window actions which use the boolean field `filter`, but I cannot get what it does.

Does anyone know what are these fields for and which values accepts `usage`?

Comment: Very interesting question. I think both fields aren't used anymore. For `usage` i suspect that it was used to filter out actions for the "home menu" of a user (debug mode settings page user form). I have no idea for what `filter` was or is used at all.